# Need some help with a seemingly simple question

Tags: aircraft-performance

An aircraft flies from A to B, distance 155 nm, in 1 hour and 23 minutes. If there is a tailwind of 12 kts the TAS is?

Comment: Are you unable to calculate the ground speed from that information?  Basic algebra.

Comment: How would you calculate the speed of a vehicle from time and distance information when there is no wind?

Comment: The TAS is **not affected by the wind**. The aircraft flies within the mass of air, and the TAS is the speed of the aircraft with respect to that mass of air. The only speed affected by the wind is the groundspeed...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (a small amount of rounding, not considering instrument error -basic)

Speed = Distance x 60/Time (in minutes)

Speed = 155 x 60/83(minutes)

Speed = 112 nmh

Speed of 112 nmh consists of 100 kts TAS and 12 kts Tailwind.

Then, TAS = 100 kts.